# Simple Implementation of Linked List in C Wrong Answer

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I am new to data structures in C. I want to implement a dictionary data structure through linked list.

I expect the following output:

> Pankaj=10
>
> Pankaj=20
>
> Kumar=30
>
> Kumar=30
>
> Kumar=30

But instead I am getting some warnings and errors which I am not able to correct:

```
justprint.c: In function ‘push’:
justprint.c:19:15: warning: assignment to ‘int’ from ‘void *’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   node->phone = malloc(sizeof(int));
               ^
justprint.c: In function ‘main’:
justprint.c:50:12: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘push’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
       push(&start, &phone[i], *name[i]);
            ^~~~~~
justprint.c:13:28: note: expected ‘struct nodetype *’ but argument is of type ‘struct nodetype **’
 void push(struct nodetype *head, int *phone, char *name[]) {
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~
justprint.c:50:31: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘push’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
       push(&start, &phone[i], *name[i]);
                               ^~~~~~~~
justprint.c:13:52: note: expected ‘char **’ but argument is of type ‘char’
 void push(struct nodetype *head, int *phone, char *name[]) {
                                              ~~~~~~^~~~~~
Segmentation fault
```

Here is my complete code in C:

Note that I am adding new data to the head of the linked list. I am facing problem printing the strings and getting rid of errors and warnings.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

struct nodetype{
    int phone;
    char **name;
    struct nodetype * next;
};

struct nodetype *head = NULL;

void push(struct nodetype *head, int *phone, char *name[]) {

  struct nodetype* node = malloc(sizeof(struct nodetype));

  size_t size=strlen(*name);

  node->name = malloc(size);

  node->next = head;

  int i; 
  for (i=0; i<size; i++) 
    *(node->name + i) = *(name + i); 
  (node->phone)=*phone;

  *head = *node;

}

void print(struct nodetype *node) 
{ 
    while (node != NULL) 
    { 
      printf("%s=%d\n", *node->name, node->phone);
      node = node->next; 
    } 
} 

int main() 
{ 
    struct nodetype *start = NULL; 

    int phone[] = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50}, i;
    char *name[] = {"Pankaj","Pankaj","Kumar","Kumar","Kumar"};
    for (i=0; i<5; i++) 
      push(start, &phone[i], &name[i]);
    print(start); 

    return 0; 
}
```

I have read a lot of online articles on linked list, dictionary, pointers, etc with each having its own method of implementation leaving me confused. I have read as much as I could.

Comment: A couple of comments
a) never cast the return value from malloc
b) call push() with name[i] instead of *name[i]
c) name should be const char *name[].
d) maybe make phone int, instead of int*
e) size should have type size_t, not unsigned.
f) copy name using strcpy instead of the for-loop

Best of luck

Comment: Read carefully what the compiler is complaining about, there are quite a few explicit things in there. If you don't understand those warnings/errors (especially why the `segmentation fauilt` happens), it just means you have to take a step back and first understand data types and how memory allocation works. Only then try some data structures.

Comment: `phone` is an `int`, not a pointer.  You don't need to call `malloc` to allocate storage for it, it's already there.  Just use it.

Comment: normally when you get a warning in regard to malloc e.g. `warning: assignment to ‘int’ from ‘void *`’ it means you are compiling the code as C++ code. Make sure you are using the C compile switch. You should not need to cast the return value of malloc

Comment: seems odd that you have declared name as char** name, one * would do. that is probably the cause of your misfortunes

Comment: Your listed code doesn't correspond to the warning messages. Make sure they correspond, otherwise your question, and possibly the answer(s) as well, make less sense.

Comment: sorry, I edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of wrong in your code which result in Undefined behavior.

Following are the few.

1. `void push(struct nodetype *head, int *phone, char *name[]`) should be

   `void push(struct nodetype **head, int phone, char name[])`

   if you are intended to change the `head`.
2. `node->phone = malloc(sizeof(int));` since `phone` is of type `int` don't allocate memory.

Your code should look like below,

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

struct nodetype{
    int phone;
    char *name;
    struct nodetype * next;
};

struct nodetype *head = NULL;

void push(struct nodetype **head, int phone, char name[]) {

  struct nodetype* node = malloc(sizeof(struct nodetype));

  unsigned size=strlen(name);
  node->name = malloc(size+1);

  node->next = *head;

  int i; 
  for (i=0; i<=size; i++) 
    node->name[i] = name[i];
  node->phone=phone;

  *head = node;

}

void print(struct nodetype *node) 
{ 
    while (node != NULL)
    {
      printf("%s=%d\n", node->name, node->phone);
      node = node->next;
    }
} 

int main() 
{  
    int phone[] = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50}, i;
    char *name[] = {"Pankaj","Pankaj","Kumar","Kumar","Kumar"};
    for (i=0; i<5; i++) 
      push(&head, phone[i], name[i]);
    print(head); 

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Thankyou :) You are a life saver

Comment: @PankajKumar Happy to help :)